# Routing error with forms for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `rounds` resource nested within the `cases` resources, so my `routes.rb` file looks like this:

```
resources :cases do
  resources :rounds
end
```

My `create` action in the controller looks like this:

```
def create
  @round = Round.new(round_params)
  if @round.save
    flash[:success] = "Round added"
    redirect_to case_path(id: @round.case_id)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

and my `_round_form.html.erb` view looks like this:

```
<%= form_for [@case, @round] do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @round %>

    ...

    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary form-button case-button" %>
<% end %>
```

For some reason, when I properly create a round, it works, but when I submit a round with errors, instead of rendering the error messages, it gives me this error:

```
undefined method rounds_path' for #<#<Class:0xc8b7508>:0xc8b6da0>
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't it be looking for `new_case_round_path`, instead of `rounds_path`?

Thew new action, if that helps:

```
def new
  id = params[:case_id]
  unless id
    flash[:danger] = "You must pick a case before trying to log a round"
    redirect_to 'pick_case'
  end
  @case = Case.find(id)
  @side_options = @case.sides.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }
  @round = Round.new
end
```

Comment: Your `@case` is nil. In which view page/action you are calling `_round_form.html.erb`?

Comment: I render `round_form` in `new.html.erb`

Comment: How you are getting `params[:case_id]`?

Comment: Just realized my error, you were right and I used params[:case_id] to fix it. I'll post the change as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have the `@case` value, Try this:

```
<%= form_for([@case, @round]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @round %>
  ...

  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary form-button case-button" %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**

```
def new
  @side_options = @case.sides.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }
  @round = @case.rounds.new
end

private

def set_case
   @case = Case.find(params[:case_id])
end
```

Comment: I have the `@case` value when I submit the form, but since it's routing to the wrong path, it won't have the `@case` value, will it? I added my `new` action to the original post, if that helps anything.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the my @case was nil, so I added `@case = Case.find(params[:case_id])` to the else branch of my create action

Comment: Great! I totally missed the point of submitting the form with errors.